# Getting an answer from a page postback with HTML\JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have an HTML "Contact us" form which I plant on my client's HTML page,this form has an 'action' property with value that leads to my production system.
When my production system gets the form , it runs a vital code that arranges the type of request by type of request and perform some other QA at the code behind.. 
In case that the page has an error **within our production system**, we would like to notify the user that completed the form at our clients side that there was an error.
The problem is that when  the form was sent we have no way to get back to the first form as a post was fired.

My question is , if there is any way to come back to the same page where the post was sent to the original page so we can notify the error AFTER the page was sent?

In other words, I need the form to be sent to the a address at the action property , and still make the browser stay at the same page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed a ReturnURL as part of the post data, that would identify where the post came from. Or perhaps embedding a customer code would be a better idea, that way you are not blindly redirecting to a URL (which could be hacked).

Comment: Thanks for you replay,unfortunately that doesn't help me, I need the form to be sent to the a address at the action property , and still make the browser stay at the same page.

Comment: Then maybe an AJAX/JSON request would better suit the situation?

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could attach an example :)